# How to use define or something else to eliminate semicolon - ; - in constructor definition?

Tags: c++

I want to eliminate the semicolon - ; - in the following constructor:

```
#define OBJECT{} JSON{};
JSON(emptyObj) = OBJECT{}
```

but when I type the following code the compiler tells me that it needs a whitespace, which means:

```
#define OBJECT {} JSON{};
JSON(emptyObj) = OBJECT{}
```

Which again is not what i want, so in order to make the definition work:

```
JSON(emptyObj) = OBJECT{}
```

I can do the following:

```
#define OBJECT JSON
#define {} {};
```

But than again the second define isnt working due to define shortcomings.

*My main problem is the semicolon in the end of the line, is there a way to eliminate the semicolon with or without define ?*

Comment: It's simply not possible using the syntax you want to use. You can't really use the preprocessor to change the base language, and neither *should* you.

Comment: The rules for defining the names for the preprocessor defines/macros are simply the same as for the language. You cannot have "{" or "}" in the name of the macro. You can try `#define OBJECT() JSON{};` but as per @Someprogrammerdude, these kind of games are not recommended at all.

Comment: So if i want to eliminate the semicolon ";" there is simply no way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i want to create a library of JSON variables for c++